# How to bring up Find dialog from a web browser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control which has navigated to a given page and is ready. Now I want to bring up the Internet explorer find dialogbox whenever the user clicks a specific button on my page. The user can already bring up the find dialog box by clicking 'ctrl+f', but I want a separate button for this action too.

I have found this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329014

But It have the following issues with it:

1. The page says that this method might not work on later versions of Internet explorer:

   > Warning This sample uses an
   >   undocumented command-group GUID that
   >   is subject to change in the future.
   >   Although this sample was tested to
   >   work correctly with Internet Explorer
   >   6 and earlier, there is no guarantee
   >   that these techniques will continue to
   >   work successfully in future versions.
2. I cant compile the code. I have added the references described in the page but I get errors telling AxSHDocVw namespace could not be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution myself:
If the web browser control name is "web", you can send the "Crtl+f" key to it with the following code:

```
web.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^f");
```

I tested this and it brought up the find dialog box on Internet explorer 8.

Comment: This code also uses an undocumented shortcut key that is subject to change in the future (though I doubt Microsoft would change it in the near future), and requires the webbrowser control to have the input focus.

It is not that hard to call body.createtextrange, then call findText and select on the text range.

Comment: This is a typical beginner error. How do you know that the shortcut for "Find" is always "F" in all languages? It may be any other letter in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows7 and .Net4.0 / WPF (not Win Forms). The solution with

```
web.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^f");
```

didn't work for me. First, the send command throws System.InvalidOperationException (saying that my application does not process event and that I should use SendKeys.SendWait()). Secondly, SendKeys.SendWait("^f") just does nothing.

My solution requires to focus the document window instead of the browser window:

```
System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser HtmlView;  //from xaml
HTMLDocument HtmlDoc { get { return (HTMLDocument)HtmlView.Document; } }
HtmlDoc.parentWindow.focus();  //when focusing this window sending Ctr-F has an effect
```

Next I use keybd_event() to send the key message

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, 
                               UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

byte vKey_f = 0x46;
byte vKey_ctr = 0x11;
byte f_down = 0x21;
byte f_up = 0xa1;
byte ctrl_down = 0x1d;
byte ctrl_up = 0x9d;
byte event_keyup = 0x0002;

keybd_event(vKey_ctr, ctrl_down, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); // Ctrl Press
keybd_event(vKey_f, f_down, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); // f Press
keybd_event(vKey_f, f_up, event_keyup, UIntPtr.Zero); // f Release
keybd_event(vKey_ctr, ctrl_up, event_keyup, UIntPtr.Zero); // Ctrl Release
```

Why "^f" does not work in my case - I don't know. But keybd_event() works fine although msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) states "This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.". I tried SendInput() but couldn't see an effect.

Further info to keybd_event():

- Scan codes: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc
- Virtual Key Codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx