# How to search for text on a page in WebBrowser? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

WebBrowser does not contain a built-in function for searching text in the browser *(for example wbSambple.FindText())*, but by pressing the CTRL + F, [this window appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0h5r.jpg)

How can i call this window? Maybe I should press the hotkey programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bring up Find dialog from a web browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590483/how-to-bring-up-find-dialog-from-a-web-browser-control)

Comment: Do you want to give the user the possibility to find text in the browser, or you want to find some words programmatically for next treatments ?